# Make font italic and bold

Tags: c#, fonts

How do you apply multiple font styles to text?

```
System.Drawing.Font MyFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
    thisTempLabel.LabelFont,
    ((float)thisTempLabel.fontSize),
    FontStyle.Bold + FontStyle.Italic,    // + obviously doesn't work, but what am I meant to do?
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel
);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want to apply more than one font styles to same set of characters? How is that possible? Or do you want to apply different styles to different characters in the same word?

Comment: @Unmesh, I want it to be Italic and Bold.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
System.Drawing.Font MyFont = new System.Drawing.Font(
    thisTempLabel.LabelFont,
    ((float)thisTempLabel.fontSize),
    FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic,
    GraphicsUnit.Pixel
);
```

Maybe you wanted to use the OR operator (`|`)

Comment: That seems to work thanks!  I don't understand the logic of it though?

Comment: @Tom - it's a "bitwise OR" operator. The underlying values of the FontStyles enum (that must have a `[Flags]` attribute) are designed to be combined in this way.

Comment: @Hans, thanks, I think I get it now, so | will evaluate all the conditions regardless of it any of them are true/false?

Comment: @Tom - that's the way it works for bools. For integers it combines the bits: 0011 | 0101 == 0111 (3|5==7)

Comment: Enums are basically integers. As Hans said, there are special enumerations flagged with [Flags] attribute so that the binary representation of each value is such that it has only one 1 (sorry for all word-games in my post...) and all 0s, and no other value has 1 in that position. So, bitwising ANDing and ORing keeps information about all the values chosen. When the back-end reads the value, it tests against the "activation" of a flag by ANDing it with the value to test (so if (value && FontStyle.italic) renderItalic(), something like that)

Comment: @dj @hans, ahhhh ok!  So the enum for font style will be like 0000 and then each style is like 1000 0100 0010 0001 and we combine them all to make a 1111 for all to be set to true right?

Comment: @tom: exactly. 0000 is usually the "default" or "empty" value

Answer (score 11):

`FontStyle` is a flag enum and therefore you can set multiple styles by:

```
FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it's FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic

You generally use the pipe (bitwise OR) symbol to combine multiple flags in these functions

This page explains it

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpLogicalBitwiseOps_2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think you could benefit from a Font class:

```
/*controlName*/.SelectionFont=new Font(maintext.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was writing a simple Text Editor and I had the same problem, I didn't find anything helpful on the internet. The if , else if method isn't optimal if there are many buttons in the form, so I thought why not take the existing font.style and just add to it using |  symbol like people suggested above. I tested this code and it works. I call this method from pictureBox I click.

Update. I found a bug. when you deselect a font, it resets all others to regular too. But the code that combines them works.

```
private void ChangeFontStyle(PictureBox p)
        {
            if (p == pictureBox1)
            {
                if (BClicked)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
                }
                else 
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Regular);
                }
            }
            else if (p == pictureBox2)
            {
                if (IClicked)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Italic);
                }
                else 
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font,  richTextBox1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Regular);
                }
            }
            else if (p == pictureBox3)
            {
                if (UClicked)
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Style | FontStyle.Underline);
                }
                else
                {
                    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Regular);
                }
            }
        }
```

P.S I used picture boxes instead of buttons and boolean variables like BClicked indicate whether they are activated or not.