# Why is the fontstyle enumeration in C# missing bold italic?

Tags: c#, fonts, font-face

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# Make font italic and bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350676/c-sharp-make-font-italic-and-bold)

How do i set the font style of a font to bold italic?

I am unable to set the fontstyle of font to bold italic.. where and how can i set it >?

Comment: System.Drawing.Font? WPF fonts?

Comment: Ask duplicate question... still get 5 correct answers... accept none of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FontStyle` is a `Flags` enumeration.  You send bold and italic by or'ing them together: `FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic
```

(FontStyle is decorated with FlagsAttribute which allows combining options this way)

Answer (score 1):

The `FontStyle` is a `Flags` enum:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum FontStyle
```

use it like

```
x.FontStyle = FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic;
```

OR

```
Button1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif,
            12.0F, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bitmask enumeration. To combine members use the bit-wise OR operator (|) like this:

```
label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
```

See also [Using a bitmask in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261451/using-a-bitmask-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

The [FontStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx) Enumeration uses the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) thus you can use bitwise operators to pass multiple FontStyles as a single parameter.

```
if (Button1.Font.Style != FontStyle.Bold || Button1.Font.Style != FontStyle.Italic)
            Button1.Font = new Font(Button1.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Italic);
```